# Using AddJoin in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, model

I'm trying to join 8000+ daily rain tables to one climatic stations shape. The goal is to get 8000+ daily rain point features. I used to work with the next arcgis model, but now i'm trying to put it in a script.

[image: This is my model]

As I'm new to python, I worked my way to this script:

```
            # Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Definir espacio de trabajo:
arcpy.env.workspace = r'E:\CLD_WEAP\ppt.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Definir variables locales:
layerName = r'E:\CLD_WEAP\ppt.gdb\estaciones'
in_field = "code"
join_table = arcpy.ListTables ("*tr")
join_field = "Transposed"

print join_table

for table in join_table:
    output = table + "_j"
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, in_field, join_table, join_field, "KEEP_ALL")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, output)
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management (layerName)
    print "output"
print "P R O C E S O   T E R M I N A D O"
```

I'm getting this error, and don't know what to do...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CLD_WEAP\scripts\join_1.py", line 22, in <module>
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, in_field, join_table, join_field, "KEEP_
ALL")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6120, in AddJoin raise e RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that my goal is to create 8000+ daily rain point shapes based on the joins.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Edit the post with that additional point, don't add as a comment. Did the process work as a Model?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, sorry, i'm new... The model worked fine in other jobs... this time is not working

Comment: The reason is because join 'from' features must be a Layer not a FeatureClass.. use MakeFeatureLayer_management to make your r'E:\CLD_WEAP\ppt.gdb\estaciones' into a Layer object for joining.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm going to try this. One question: The MakeFeatureLayer is made just once?

Comment: Yes, only once. See the answer with minimal changes to your code.

Answer (score 4):

The [Add Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000064000000) tool needs an input Layer (or table view) object, not a feature class. I suspect the reason it was working before is because you were running the model in ArcMap where all inputs are Layers.

The [make feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) need only be done once:

```
import arcpy

# Definir espacio de trabajo:
arcpy.env.workspace = r'E:\CLD_WEAP\ppt.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Definir variables locales:
layerName = 'Layer' # the layer made from inFeatures
inFeatures = r'E:\CLD_WEAP\ppt.gdb\estaciones' # the features to be joined from
in_field = "code"
join_table = arcpy.ListTables ("*tr")
join_field = "Transposed"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures,layerName)
print join_table

for table in join_table:
    output = table + "_j"
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, in_field, join_table, join_field, "KEEP_ALL")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, output)
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management (layerName)
    print "output {}".format(output) # report each output
print "P R O C E S O   T E R M I N A D O"
```